# Powershell: exit code of .NET framework installer

Tags: powershell, exit-code

I would like to script an installation of .NET framework then SQL server.
But, I would like in first part install .NET framework quietly AND ONLY IF .NET installation is ok, then, install SQL server.

How can I be sure .NET framework is installed ? Can I use a specific exitcode ?

I would like to do something like that:

if(code_returned_by_net_installer == 0)
       
else
   write-host "it failed !"

Answer (score 0):

I thin you can test `$lastexitcode` automatic variable after the installation:

```
if( $lastexitcode -eq 0)
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to automate all installation, so is there any solution to launch SQL script after the first one (.NET) is done successfully ?